# Without yarn map-reduce work?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm studying about hadoop map-reduce on centos 6.5 and hadoop 2.7.2. I learned that hdfs is just distributed file system and Yarn administers map-reduce work, so I thought that if i don't turn on Yarn(resource manager, node manager), map-reduce doesn't work.

Therefore, I think, wordcount should not do map-reduce process in the system working only hdfs not yarn.

(on the pseudo distribute mode)

But when I turn hdfs on not Yarn as you see in the below, and execute wordcount example, it show 'map-reduce framework'. What's it meaning? Does it possible only hdfs process map-reduce without Yarn? Because Yarn manage resource and job, is it right that map-reduce doesn't work without Yarn?

[image]

```
bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.2.jar wordcount /user/input /user/output
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you paste the complete logs.

Comment: I add the log with screen shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Hadoop 2.0 YARN takes responsibility of resource management, this is true. But even without YARN the Map Reduce applications can run using the older flavor.

The mapred-site.xml has a configuration - mapreduce.framework.name

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>local</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

The above can be configured to choose whether to use YARN or not. The possible values for this property are - local, classic or yarn

The default value is "local". Set this to yarn, if you want to use YARN

Comment: As i think, when doing a map-reduce, certainly need resource management. Because to do a distributed job, we surely need resource management to distribute job to distributed node. As your answer, older flavor also do resource manage?? You mean older flavor is about library???

Comment: What I meant to state was that with "local" the task shall run using LocalJobRunner and not YARN

Comment: thanks, lastly one more answer please. If task is processed by LocalJobRunner, is the job working locally? locally mean working only one node in cluster?

Comment: It'll run on the client machine